# Jquery get array details

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm having trouble getting a response back from a Jquery ajax call...

(It's a script to authenticate a user, and needs to return their name and user ID. My understanding was that I could encode it as JSON and get the data in the format below.

**It is returning an error of "undefined" for the alert()**.

*The javascript*

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "myURL.php",
 data: {username: username, password: password},
 success: function(results) {
  //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
  alert('Hi '+results.name); //Should be "Hi Basil Fawlty"
  }
});
```

*The PHP (myURL.php)*

```
//This comes from a SQL call that returns the following name
json_encode(array(
 'id'=>1,
 'name'=>'Basil Fawlty'
));
```

Any help or ideas on where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

**Solution:** The solution was adding a dataType.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: can you post here what you get with **alert(results.responceText)** ?

Comment: I was using version 1.3.

The output was "undefined"

Comment: Thanks for the replies, specifying dataType JSON solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing `dataType: "json"`:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "myURL.php",
 dataType: "json",
 data: {username: username, password: password},
 success: function(results) {
  //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
  alert('Hi '+results.name); //Should be "Hi Basil Fawlty"
  }
});
```

Another (less verbose) alternative is [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) if you know you are getting JSON.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery < 1.4, you must specify `dataType: "json"`.

As of 1.4, [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) defaults to:

> Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script,
>   or html)

But this requires that the response header contains the string "json". So you'll want to send:

`header('Content-type: application/json');`

This newly added flexibility with dataType allows handlers to respond to multiple returned types.

If the problem continues, you'll want to alert the entire response `alert(results);` to see what's actually being returned.

Lot of similar answers here. Not sure who started it but whoever did no doubt invaded Poland.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd up vote twice if I could for the Poland comment!

Comment: We were all composing at the same time I think.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set your `dataType` to JSON so you get the response object in the success method, like this:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "myURL.php",
 dataType: "json",
 data: {username: username, password: password},
 success: function(results) {
  alert('Hi '+results.name);
 }
});
```

[Details for `dataType` can be found here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Alternatively, [you can do this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$.getJSON( "myURL.php", {username: username, password: password}, 
  function(results) {
    alert('Hi '+results.name);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the dataType and the info on getJSON.

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that you are expecting JSON but you are getting a string.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to specify a dataType in the request like so:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "myURL.php",
 data: {username: username, password: password},
 dataType: "json", 
 success: function(results) {
  //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
  alert('Hi '+results.name); //Should be "Hi Basil Fawlty"
  }
});
```

or you can set the content type from php using

```
header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
```